# Dynamic Jquery Validation of Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm attempting to dynamically add jquery validation to some dynamically created items in my asp.net webforms project (asp:checkbox, asp:textbox, infragistics:webnumericeditor, asp:dropdownlist) and can get it working correctly for all items except the dropdownlist.

The code I'm using is:

```
var oID = this.ObjectID;
$("#" + oID).rules("add", {
    required: {
        depends: function (element) {
            return $("#" + oID + " option:selected").val() == 0;
        }
     },
     messages: {
         required: "*"
     }
 })
```

The dropdownlist item is generated from codebehind with a 'Please Select...' item inserted at position 0 like so

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
...
ddl.DataBind();
ListItem li = new ListItem("Please Select...", "0");
ddl.Items.Insert(0, li);
```

The validation is never firing though. I added an alert to fire when the item gets generated and that returns 0 correctly so I'm unsure why the validation isn't working.

This is my first time using jquery validation so I'm expecting it to be something obvious and simple but the methods I've tried thus far haven't yielded any results so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Instead of assigning '0' value for dropdown list assign the value as ' ' for your default item i.e "Please Select" Item

Comment: @bhanu.cs Brilliant! That worked, if you can post this as an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: Good to hear that it has helped you.Sure I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListItem li = new ListItem("Please Select...", " ");
```

Assign ' ' for your default item instead of assigning to a value of '0'